# Android 9-patch batch

Tags: android

I am using the Android 9-patch tool to generate my 9-patch images. I have to support a number of different resolutions and button states. This means that for a single 9-patch button I need to generate 16 separate assets. Currently I am generating each of these separately using the Android 9-patch tool interface which is taking a lot of my time. If I was able to specify the 9-patch dot for a range of buttons which have the same properties this would save me a lot of time. Is there the equivalent of a command line tool or other approach which would help.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

[Here](https://github.com/SpatialInteractive/9-patchedit) is a nifty looking tool I just found. I cannot verify its accuracy or stability, but it claims to do what you want.

Comment: I was so desperate that I almost wrote my own tool. 9pedit is great. It's  exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use the Android Asset Studio at http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/nine-patches.html.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there's is no tool as you like afair, but you could easily craft small script (PHP, Perl whatever) that would combine two images (main image + 9-patch dots) together. Or you can save dots separately and then load it into GIMP or Photoshop as layers and export as single final 9patch PNG.